# How to disable the keyboard's numeric keypad?

Tags: x11, keyboard-layout

I want to disable all numpad keys; the ones located on the right side of my keyboard.

How can I do this? Of course, I would also like to know how to revert the action an re-enable the numeric keypad.

I have tried different things, such as remapping:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = """
```

But I get an error:

```
xmodmap commandline1: bad keycode value
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable them via `XKB` you could comment them out in your *X* `keycodes` file (the one that corresponds to your keyboard - *linux* uses `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev`). Numpad key codes start with `<KP...` so you could use the following to prepend those lines with `//kp_dsbl` (`//` is the comment and `kp_dsbl` is some arbitrary string that you can use later to identify those lines if you want to revert changes):

```
sed -i '/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}<KP/s|^|//kp_dsbl|' /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
```

or

```
ed -s /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev <<\IN
g/^[[:blank:]]\{1,\}<KP/s|^|//kp_dsbl|
w
q
IN
```

To re-enable them:

```
sed -i 's|^//kp_dsbl||' /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev
```

or

```
ed -s /usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev <<\IN
,s|^//kp_dsbl||
w
q
IN
```

Comment: Keep in mind that future upgrades of `xkeyboard-config` (the package that owns the keycode definitions file) may overwrite your changes; in that case you'll have to run that `ed/sed` command again.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that the # is used to indicate the keycode number, the first problem I notice is shell quoting. The shell implicitly concatenates strings unless separated.

So when you type

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = """
```

it is equivalent to

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = "
```

chances are you ment to type one of these

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = \"\""
xmodmap -e 'keycode # = ""'
xmodmap -e "keycode # = "\"\"
xmodmap -e "keycode # = "'""'
```

Even so, that may not do what you want. My memory is rusty but you may need to use a null keysym.

```
xmodmap -e "keycode # = null"
```

In general I believe that you are on the right path of removing and then later adding the mappings. Adding them should be easy.

Comment: It gaves the same error: xmodmap commandline1: bad keycode value. Is there a way maybe to declade it by Num Pad number instead of #?

Answer (score 1):

If `xmodmap` tells you “bad keycode value”, it means you passed a bad keycode value. You can use the program `xev` to see what keycode a key sends: launch it from a terminal, press the key in the xev window, and watch the `KeyPress` event appearing in the terminal. Use the correct value where you wrote `#` in your question.

You can also reassign keys based on the symbolic keysym that they currently send. You can disable the keypad with something like

```
xmodmap <<EOF
keysym KP_0 =
…
keysym KP_Decimal =
keysym KP_Enter =
keysym KP_Plus =
keysym KP_Minus =
keysym KP_Multiply =
keysym KP_Divide =
EOF
```

You will need to remember the keycodes to restore the keypad functionality however. You can save it to a file at the beginning:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep KP_ >keypad.xmodmap
```

There may be a more convenient way with XKB.