# How to remap keyboard keys based on how long you hold the key

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xkb

I would like to remap the keys on my number pad so that they behave differently depending on how long the key is pressed.  Here's an example:

If I hold the Numpad 9 key down for less than 300ms it will send the "previous tab" key command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>

If I hold the Numpad 9 key down for 300-599ms it will send the "new tab" key command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

If I hold the Numpad 9 key down for 600-899ms it will send the "close tab/window" key command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

If I hold the Numpad 9 key down for more than 899ms, it does nothing in case I missed the time window I wanted.

On Windows I could do this with AutoHotKey and on OS X I could do this with ControllerMate, but I cannot find a tool on UNIX/Linux that allows key remapping based on how long a key is held.

If you are aware of a tool that can solve my problem, please make sure to  provide a script or code sample that demonstrates the conditional key hold duration behavior I described above.  It doesn't need to be the full code to solve my example, but it should be enough for me to repurpose it for my example.

Comment: This is such an outlandish thing to do.  How are you going to time your 600 millisecond press?  :D  +1 for crazy idea.

Comment: Just to add some spice to your life, you should add a time window from 347 to 350 ms that will force-shutdown your computer.  ;)

Comment: @Wildcard I actually use the number pad on my Razer Naga for this and when I first implemented the idea with AutoHotKey on Windows I used 300-400ms time windows, but now that I've been using this system for a while, I use use time windows about 200ms apart, and I can get the desired time window about 99% of the time.  It's very similar to the way you would communicate with morse code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just wrote this in **C**:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curses.h>
#include <time.h> //time(0)
#include <sys/time.h>                // gettimeofday()
#include <stdlib.h>

void waitFor (unsigned int secs) {
    //credit: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3930477/1074998
    unsigned int retTime = time(0) + secs;   // Get finishing time.
    while (time(0) < retTime);               // Loop until it arrives.
}

int
main(void) {

    struct timeval t0, t1, t2, t3;
    double elapsedTime;

    clock_t elapsed_t = 0;
    int c = 0x35;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    noecho();
    keypad(stdscr, TRUE);

    halfdelay(5); //increae the number if not working //adjust below `if (elapsedTime <= 0.n)` if this changed
    printf("\nSTART again\n");

    elapsed_t = 0;
    gettimeofday(&t0, NULL);

    float diff;

    int first = 1;
    int atleast_one = 0;

      while( getch() == c) { //while repeating same char, else(ffff ffff in my system) break

            int atleast_one = 1;

            if (first == 1) {
                gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
                first = 0;
            }

            //printf("DEBUG 1 %x!\n", c);
            gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
            elapsedTime = (t2.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + ((t2.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000000.0); 

            if (elapsedTime > 1) { //hit max time

                printf("Hit Max, quit now. %f\n", elapsedTime);
                system("gnome-terminal");
                //waitFor(4);

                int cdd;
                while ((cdd = getch()) != '\n' && cdd != EOF);
                endwin();

                exit(0);
            }

            if(halfdelay(1) == ERR) { //increae the number if not working
                //printf("DEBUG 2\n");
                //waitFor(4);
                break; 
                }
            else {
                //printf("DEBUG 3\n");
                }
        }

    if (atleast_one == 0) {
            //gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
            t1 = t0;
    }

    gettimeofday(&t3, NULL);
    elapsedTime = (t3.tv_sec - t1.tv_sec) + ((t3.tv_usec - t1.tv_usec)/1000000.0); 
    printf("Normal quit %f\n", elapsedTime);
    if (elapsedTime > 0.6) { //this number based on halfdelay above
        system("gedit &");
        //system("xdotool key shift+left &");
        //system("mplayer -vo caca -quiet 'video.mp4' &");
        //waitFor(4);
    }
    else if (elapsedTime <= 0.6) {
        system("xdotool key ctrl+shift+t &");
        //waitFor(4);
    }

    int cdd;
    while ( (cdd = getch() ) != '\n' && cdd != EOF);
    endwin();
    return 0; 

}
```

Use `showkey -a` to get the bind keycode:

```
xb@dnxb:/tmp$ sudo showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^[[24~   27 0033 0x1b #pressed F12
         91 0133 0x5b
         50 0062 0x32
         52 0064 0x34
        126 0176 0x7e
5        53 0065 0x35 #pressed Numpad 5, 5 is the keycode used in `bind`
^C        3 0003 0x03
^D        4 0004 0x04
xb@dnxb:/tmp$
```

Put the bind keycode 5 and its command(e.g. run `/tmp/.a.out`) in ~/.bashrc:

```
bind '"5":"/tmp/a.out\n"'
```

Note that relevant keycode need to change in the source code too (the hex value can get from `sudo showkey -a` above too):

```
int c = 0x35;
```

Compile with (output to `/tmp/a.out` in my example):

```
cc filename.c -lcurses
```

**Demonstration:**

Numpad 5, short press open new tab, medium press open gedit, and long press open gnome-terminal.

[image]

This is not direct applicable in any window on gnome desktop manager, but i think it should give you some idea how (hard) to implement it. It work in Virtual Console(Ctrl+Alt+N) too, and work in some terminal emulator (e.g. konsole, gnome-terminal, xterm).

p/s: I'm not a c programmer, so forgive me if this code is not optimized.

**[UPDATE]**

The previous answer only work in shell and required focus, so i think parse the /dev/input/eventX is the solution to work in entire X session.

I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I play around with `evtest` utility and modified the bottom part of [evtest.c](http://elinux.org/images/9/93/Evtest.c) with my own code:

```
int onHold = 0;
struct timeval t0;
double elapsedTime;
int hitMax = 0;

while (1) {
    rd = read(fd, ev, sizeof(struct input_event) * 64);

    if (rd < (int) sizeof(struct input_event)) {
        perror("\nevtest: error reading");
        return 1;
    }

    system("echo 'running' >/tmp/l_is_running 2>/tmp/l_isrunning_E &");
    for (i = 0; i < rd / sizeof(struct input_event); i++) {

        //system("date >/tmp/l_date 2>/tmp/l_dateE &");

        if (ev[i].type == EV_KEY) {
            if ( (ev[i].code == 76) ) {

                if (!onHold) {
                    onHold = 1;
                    t0 = ev[i].time;
                    hitMax = 0;
                }
                if (!hitMax) { //to avoid hitMax still do the time checking instruction, you can remove hitMax checking if you think it's overkill, but still hitMax itself is necessary to avoid every (max) 2 seconds will repeatly system();
                    elapsedTime = (ev[i].time.tv_sec - t0.tv_sec) + ((ev[i].time.tv_usec - t0.tv_usec)/1000000.0);
                    printf("elapsedTime: %f\n", elapsedTime);
                    if (elapsedTime > 2) {
                        hitMax = 1;
                        printf("perform max time action\n");
                        system("su - xiaobai -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; gedit &'");
                    }
                }

                if (ev[i].value == 0)  {
                    printf("reseted ...... %d\n", ev[i].value);
                    onHold = 0;
                    if (!hitMax) {
                        if (elapsedTime > 1) { //just ensure lower than max 2 seconds
                            system("su - xiaobai -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; gnome-terminal &'");
                        } else if (elapsedTime > 0.5) { 
                            system("su - xiaobai -c \"export DISPLAY=:0; vlc '/home/xiaobai/Downloads/videos/test/Pokémon Red_Blue_Yellow Gym Leader Battle Theme Remix-CbJTkx7QUJU.mp4' &\"");
                        } else if  (elapsedTime > 0.2) {
                            system("su - xiaobai -c 'export DISPLAY=:0; nautilus &'");
                        }
                    } else { //else's max system() already perform
                        hitMax = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you should change the username (**xiaobai** is my username) part. And also the `if ( (ev[i].code == 76) ) {` is my Numpad 5 keycode, you might need to manually print the ev[i].code to double confirm. And of course you should change the video path too :)

Compile and test it directly with (the `` part is in order to get the correct `/dev/input/eventN`):

```
$ gcc /home/put_your_path/my_long_press.c -o /home/put_your_path/my_long_press; sudo /home/put_your_path/my_long_press `ls -la /dev/input/by-path/* | grep kbd |  echo "/dev/input/""$(awk -F'/' '{print $NF}')" ` &
```

Note that `/by-id/` doesn't work in Fedora 24, so i change it to /by-path/. Kali no such problem.

My desktop manager is gdm3:

```
$ cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager 
/usr/sbin/gdm3
```

So, i put this line in `/etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default` to run this command as root on gdm startup (`/etc/X11/Xsession.d/*` doesn't work):

```
/home/put_your_path/my_long_press `ls -la /dev/input/by-id/* | grep kbd |  echo "/dev/input/""$(awk -F'/' '{print $NF}')" 2>/tmp/l_gdm` 2>/tmp/l_gdmE &
```

For unknown reason /`etc/gdm/PostLogin/Default` doesn't work on Fedora 24' gdm which give me "**Permission denied**" when check `/tmp/l_gdmE` log. Manually run no problem though.

**Demonstration:**

Numpad 5, instant-press (<=0.2 second) will be ignored, short-press (0.2 to 0.5 second) open `nautilus`, medium-press (0.5 to 1 second) open `vlc` to play video, long-press (1 to 2 seconds) open `gnome-terminal`, and timeout-press (2 seconds) open `gedit`.

[image]

[I uploaded the full code(only one file) here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/limkokhole/e123de5ae0acc5e2ed026183977a68b7/raw/6fe73924f48f28fd2d9cdaa162492c5e5785d340/my_long_press.c).

**[UPDATE again]**

[1] Added multiple keys flow and fixed `notify-send` failed by define `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. 
[2] Added `XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` and `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` to ensure konsole use gnome theme gui (Change it if you're not using gnome).

[I updated my code here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/limkokhole/50042a05cb1db5b1d1f6987c93729727/raw/bdf67348432fdea6d53aaedff93703161efc7a6b/my_long_press.c).

Note that this code doesn't handle for combination keys flow, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

**UPDATE:**

There's multiple device interfaces which the /dev/input/by-path/XXX-eventN entries sequence is random. So I change the command in `/etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default` as below (`Chesen` is my keyboard name, for your case, you should changed it to `grep Razer` instead):

```
/your_path/my_long_press "$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i Chesen -A 4 | grep -P '^(?=.*sysrq)(?=.*leds)' |  tr ' ' '\n' | ls /dev/input/`grep event`)" 2>/tmp/l_gdmE &
```

You can try the eventN extract from `cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i Razer -A 4`:

```
$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i Razer -A 4
N: Name="Razer Razer Naga Chroma"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.0/0003:1532:0053.0003/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse2 event5 
--
N: Name="Razer Razer Naga Chroma"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input1
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.1/0003:1532:0053.0004/input/input7
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd event6 
--
N: Name="Razer Razer Naga Chroma"
P: Phys=usb-0000:00:14.0-1.3/input2
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-1/3-1.3/3-1.3:1.2/0003:1532:0053.0005/input/input8
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=sysrq kbd leds event7 
$
```

In this example above, only `sudo cat /dev/input/event7` will print bizarre output when click the 12 digits on Razer mouse, which has the pattern "sysrq kbd leds event7" to use in `grep -P '^(?=.*sysrq)(?=.*leds)'` above (your pattern might vary). `sudo cat /dev/input/event6` will print bizarre output only when click the middle up/down key. While `sudo cat /dev/input/event5` will print bizarre output when move your mouse and scrolling the wheel.

**[Update: Support Replug keyboard cable to reload the program]**

The following should be self-explanation:

```
$ lsusb #to know my keyboard is idVendor 0a81 and idProduct 0101
...
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard

$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/52-hole-keyboard.rules #add this line with your idVendor and idProduct above in custom udev rules file
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0a81", ATTR{idProduct}=="0101", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev", RUN+="/bin/bash -c 'echo 1 > /tmp/chesen_plugged'"

$ cat /usr/local/bin/inotifyChesenPlugged #A long run listener script to listen for modification of /tmp/chesen_plugged #Ensures `inotifywait` has been installed first.
touch /tmp/chesen_plugged
while inotifywait -q -e modify /tmp/chesen_plugged >/dev/null; do
        killall -9 my_long_press
        /usr/local/bin/startLongPress &
done

$ cat /usr/local/bin/startLongPress #the executable script run the long press executable #Change with your pattern as explained above.
#!/bin/bash
<YOUR_DIR>/my_long_press "$(cat /proc/bus/input/devices | grep -i Chesen -A 4 | grep -P '^(?=.*sysrq)(?=.*leds)' |  tr ' ' '\n' | ls /dev/input/`grep event`)" 2>/tmp/l_gdmE) & disown

$ cat /etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default #the executable startup script run listener and long press script
/usr/local/bin/inotifyChesenPlugged &
/usr/local/bin/startLongPress &
```

Comment: i assume this method requires a terminal window to be in focus while doing key presses? is there a way around this?

Comment: @kanoko I've updated the solution.

Comment: thx, i really appreciate the effort you put into this.  I will try this out.  do you think this solution will have a noticeable impact on cpu usage if i set it up with 12 different hotkeys?

Comment: @kanoko I've updated the code again to play around with multiple keys. IMHO i don't think it's noticeable impact on cpu because 10+ if-else is too subtle, and it only run the checking after read(fd, ev, sizeof(struct input_event) * 64); statement, i.e. it only run the `if-else` every key press, while i also added `if (currCode >= 59) && (currCode <= 81)` to limit the range before `if-else`.

Comment: I tried running the code after making the changes you mentioned, and it creates the process cleanly, but I'm not seeing any changes to my key presses.  I even uncommented the printf currCode line to see the key codes, but I'm not seeing anything.  I'm on Lubuntu 16.04.

Comment: @kanoko Then you should put some debugging statement e.g. `printf("track: 1\n");` start from `int main (int argc, char **argv)` and track where it stop. FYI `rd = read(fd, ev, sizeof(struct input_event) * 64);` is on onhold until key press event is received. Then `for (i = 0; i < rd / sizeof(struct input_event); i++) {` will do 2 or 3 loops(repeatedly press will 2 times). `ev[i].type == EV_KEY` is the only loop we care about. And you should manually test on terminal instead of desktop manager startup autorun. You can also install `evtest` utility to play around first.

Comment: I did that, but I'm not seeing any printf statements in the terminal when I run program using the arguments you provided.  I believe your arguments spawn the process outside of the terminal since the command prompt returns immediately after execution.

Comment: @kanoko First, ensure `ls -la /dev/input/by-path/* | grep kbd |  echo "/dev/input/""$(awk -F'/' '{print $NF}')"`return something like `/dev/input/event19`, otherwise you need to manually do `ls -la /dev/input/by-path/` to find out the correct `/dev/input/eventN` because `grep kbd` might not portable. `sudo cat /dev/input/event19` will direct print something in terminal if this is your correct keyboard. After that you can simplify the command, e.g. `sudo ./my_long_press /dev/input/event19` to test.

Comment: Here's an example output: " [1] 1653 " However, if i use your "event19" argument, I get asked sudo password and then the following: " evtest:  No such file or directory " I've already installed evtest and get command option help response when i run "evtest" from command-line

Comment: FYI: evtest is currently installed in /usr/bin and my file is located in home/username/Downloads

Comment: @kanoko [1] " [1] 1653 " is PID 1653 which indicated you just run the command as background job, due to you trailing the command with `&`. Try to run `jobs` command to list background jobs. Run `fg` can make it foreground. Use `ps aux | grep program_name_regex` to check too. [2] "No such file or directory" because `/dev/input/event19` file doesn't exist which is so normal because we have different system state. Use `ls -laR /dev/input` to check your system's eventN. You will see a lot of symlink inside `/dev/input/by-path` directory which used by my command try to grep valid eventN but failed.

Comment: great!  i found out event18 is the one i want.  everything is working when i specify that as the argument.  now is there a way to prevent the actual numpad key from being output so only the time window function occurs during a key press?

Comment: @kanoko You can refer this answer, http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/240894/64403  to learn how to disable numpad keys. Note that eventN might keep changing in next boot. So you should figure out the pattern(my pattern is the filename contains "kbd" keyword) to `grep` the event in `/etc/gdm3/PostLogin/Default`. Run `ls -la /dev/input/by-id/` to find out the pattern. My output is `/dev/input/by-id/usb-CHESEN_USB_Keyboard-event-kbd -> ../event1
`

Comment: that worked!  i only have one last thing to add.  for three of these keys (lets say num4, num5, num6) i also have them function as shift, alt, and ctrl modifier keys while they are held, on top of their normal time window behavior.  is this possible with the evtest code?

Comment: @kanoko I've updated the code, a new function called `doModifier()` has been added. Tested in firefox/konsole to open new tab by pressing Numpad 4+6+t and close tab by pressing Numpad 6+D(Konsole) or Numpad 6+W(Firefox), while still allow you trigger xcock/konsole/gedit  based on how long you hold (I also set NULL checking behind `> 0.2 seconds` condition to allow you disable `0.2-0.5`'s key to avoid trigger too fast when modifier is used). The code logic is quite straightforward and shouldn't be hard to modify based on your needs :)

Comment: you are amazing!!! thank you so much for all of your help.  if you ever get a chance to try this with an MMO numpad mouse like Razer Naga, i swear it will change your life.  I can show you my key mappings if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

You might find a tool that works with a particular set of programs, but there will be no globally-usable tool because time-related behavior is done in applications in X, rather than by the windowing system.

Answer (score 0):

did you check the Xmodmap ?

xmodmap is a utility for modifying keymaps and pointer button mappings in Xorg

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmodmap

Comment: But it doesn't know about time delays :-)