# Does xkb support complex key combinations such as mapping s+hjkl to left, down, up, and right?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, xkb

I'm trying to configure xkb to make it register `left`, `down`, `up`, and `right` arrow when I hold `s` (the letter) and press `h`, `j`, `k`, or `l` (similar to Karabiner on MacOS). This will allow navigation in vim or terminal without leaving the middle row. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean `s` as in the Super modifier (which was my understanding), or `s` as in insert the letter `s` with a short press but act as a modifier with a long press?

Comment: `s` as in the letter that's part of the asdf row and, as you described, a short press would work as the letter and a long press would work as a modifier.

Comment: Another answer details how to accomplish this. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320373/how-to-remap-keyboard-keys-based-on-how-long-you-hold-the-key

Comment: xkb probably can't do this by itself.  use a lower-level tool instead (`evdev` or `libinput`-based) -- projects like [`evrouter`](https://www.bedroomlan.org/projects/evrouter), [`evdevremapkeys`](https://github.com/philipl/evdevremapkeys), or [`autokey`](https://github.com/autokey/autokey).